# Unable to subset Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have the following data in a data frame named `in_file`:

```
Client  Value_01   Value_02   Date
ABC     100       500       2016-09-01T
ABC     14        90        2016-09-02T
DEF     95        1000      2016-09-01T
DEF     200       600       2016-09-02T
GHI     75        19        2016-09-01T
GHI     300       700       2016-09-02T
JKL     50        02        2016-09-01T
JKL     400       800       2016-09-02T
```

I subset the data frame with the following (which we'll call 'subset 1'):

```
df_01 = in_file.loc[(in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & (in_file.Client <> 'ABC') & (in_file.Client <> 'DEF')].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)
```

and I get back:

```
Client  Value_01   Value_02   Date
GHI     75        19        2016-09-01T
JKL     50        02        2016-09-01T
```

Then, I attempt to subset the data frame with the following (which we'll call 'subset 2'):

```
df_02 = in_file.loc[(in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & (in_file.Client == 'ABC') & (in_file.Client == 'DEF')].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)
```

With 'subset 2', I get back an **empty data frame**.  But, I was expecting to see the following:

```
Client  Value_01   Value_02   Date
ABC     100       500       2016-09-01T
DEF     95        1000      2016-09-01T
```

Does anyone know why the 'subset 2' code is not returning the data frame that I expect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want `(in_file.Client == 'ABC') & (in_file.Client == 'DEF')` ? Both to be true at the same time?

Comment: try this: `in_file.loc[(in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & (in_file.Client.isin(['ABC', 'DEF'])].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)`

Comment: is there a counterpart to `isin` that would allow me to exclude certain data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

including `isin()`:

```
In [28]: in_file.loc[(in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & in_file.Client.isin(['ABC', 'DEF'])].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)
Out[28]:
  Client  Value_01  Value_02         Date
0    ABC       100       500  2016-09-01T
2    DEF        95      1000  2016-09-01T
```

excluding:

```
In [29]: in_file.loc[(in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & (~in_file.Client.isin(['ABC', 'DEF']))].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)
Out[29]:
  Client  Value_01  Value_02         Date
4    GHI        75        19  2016-09-01T
6    JKL        50         2  2016-09-01T
```

Or bit slower, but much nicer `query()` method:

```
In [30]: in_file.query("Date == '2016-09-01T' and Client in ['ABC', 'DEF']")
Out[30]:
  Client  Value_01  Value_02         Date
0    ABC       100       500  2016-09-01T
2    DEF        95      1000  2016-09-01T

In [31]: in_file.query("Date == '2016-09-01T' and Client not in ['ABC', 'DEF']")
Out[31]:
  Client  Value_01  Value_02         Date
4    GHI        75        19  2016-09-01T
6    JKL        50         2  2016-09-01T
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting conditions for your second subset dataframe

`(in_file.Client == 'ABC')` & `(in_file.Client == 'DEF')`

Can never both be true at the same time.

What you seem to be looking for is 'or' logic not '&' logic. So

`df_02 = in_file.loc[(in_file.Date == '2016-09-02T') or (in_file.Client == 'ABC') or (in_file.Client == 'DEF')].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)`

will give you

```
ABC     100       500       2016-09-01T
ABC     14        90        2016-09-02T
DEF     95        1000      2016-09-01T
DEF     200       600       2016-09-02T
GHI     300       700       2016-09-02T
JKL     400       800       2016-09-02T
```

Answer (score 0):

***Caveat*** This is not the best solution!!!
I only want to point out what you were doing wrong.
@MaxU has the best answer

define `cond2`

```
cond2 = (in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & \
        (in_file.Client == 'ABC') & \
        (in_file.Client == 'DEF')
```

This will always be `False` as `in_file.Client` can never be both `'ABC'` and `'DEF'`.  You must use 'or' `|`

Instead

```
cond2 = (in_file.Date == '2016-09-01T') & \
        ((in_file.Client == 'ABC') | (in_file.Client == 'DEF'))
```

Then

```
df_02 = in_file.loc[cond2].sort_values('Value_01', ascending=False)
df_02
```

[image]

---

## But Don't Choose This Answer

It is not as good as using `isin`